# Doing an engagement party

Tags: canon, event-photography

So, I'm doing an engagement party for my sister-in-law's sister. Now, I haven't picked up my camera in probably 3 years... just kinda fell out of it. They ask me to do it as I won't really ask for much money. We're basically setting up a photo booth and I'll just take pics of people coming in. I want the pictures to look nice, of course, so I'm just looking for any advice!

I have a Canon EOS Rebel T3 and 18-55mm and 75-300mm lenses.

Comment: What lighting equipment do you have and what do you know about flash and mixed shooting?

Comment: I honestly don't remember much, and they're just setting up some lights I think

Comment: Hi Laura! This is a question-and-answer site rather than a typical discussion forum. Is there a specific question you have? We're not really set up to address a general call for help.

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I guess which is the best lens to use and settings for an indoor photobooth like event

Comment: Does [How do I setup and capture an event photo booth?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43539/how-do-i-setup-and-capture-an-event-photo-booth) cover it?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend adding a third lens to your arsenal, a $100-$150 "nifty fifty", 50mm f/1.8.

None of the lenses you have is ideal for a photo booth. The "nifty fifty" used at a wide aperture allows you to have a shallow depth of field, so that the background becomes very soft indeed. I would use the "nifty fifty" stopped down one or two third-stops from its wide-open aperture because it's somewhat soft at the widest aperture.

If you don't have the budget for a third lens, then I would use the 18-55mm lens, probably around the focal length a "nifty fifty" would have, i.e. its long end.

The 75-300mm telephoto is not recommended, because it might be a bit too long. However, at its very shortest end (75mm) it could be used. My understanding is that the 75-300 is not a particularly good lens.